# Возможно ли отследить что кнопка нажата через if?

Tags: android, kotlin

Возник вопрос мне нужно отследить что пользователь нажал кнопку, без использования setOnClickListener то есть чтобы вышло что-то такое:

```
if(buttonNext.нажата){
   continue
  }else{
    ждать нажатия
  }
```

Comment: Чем вам не понравился стандартный слушатель?

Comment: Вам нужно завести в активити флаг, который менять в слушателе.

Comment: А можно пожалуйста пример или точное название чтобы я мог прогуглить.